# batch mkdir return codes

Tags: batch-file, mkdir

My batch script checks to see if a folder already exists and if it doesn't to make a directory.  I am running into other problems besides if the folder already is there, but I cannot place my finger on what it is. Is there a way to return an error code to determine my problem?

Code:

```
if not exist "%arcval_folder%" (
    mkdir "%arcval_folder%"
    echo Directory: "%arcval_folder%" created. 1>>"%logfile%" 2>&1
    ECHO. 1>>"%logfile%" 2>&1
)
```

I keep getting that the folder was created, even when it had not on inspection of the target location.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try checking the return of your mkdir command by using the %ERRORLEVEL% pseudo-variable:

C:\Users\DWilches>

```
C:\Users\DWilches>mkdir test

C:\Users\DWilches>echo %ERRORLEVEL%
0

C:\Users\DWilches>mkdir test
A subdirectory or file test already exists.

C:\Users\DWilches>echo %ERRORLEVEL%
1
```

Comment: That's don't tell you if the directory was NOT created.

Comment: @SachaDee I agree with you. But how to check that right?

Answer (score 1):

This will not test for **folder** existence. It test if there is a file or folder with the required name

```
if exist "c:\somefolder"
```

This will test for folder existence

```
if exist "c:\somefolder\"
```

But you have to take more things in consideration

```
set "test=c:\somewhere"

    if exist "%test%\" (
        echo Folder exists
    ) else if not exist "%test%" (
        echo No file nor folder exist with the indicated name. 
        echo Maybe, folder can be created
    ) else (
        echo There is a file with the same name as the required folder.
        echo Folder can not be created
    )
```

And, of course, if you decide to create the folder, test the errorlevel. Maybe you have not rights to create the folder.

Answer (score 1):

You can set a success variable if the command succeeds using &&.

You can set a flag and perform the 'mkdir' and double check the success all on one line like this:

```
set folder=test
set OK=false & mkdir %folder% && if exist %folder% set OK=true
```

After, check for OK like this:

```
if (%OK%)=(true)(
     echo made dir %folder%
     goto:doSomethingUseful
)else(
     echo failed to make dir %folder%
     goto:whatIdoWhenThisFailed    
)
```

Notes:

- In DOS, the command after '&&' will only be run if the prior command
  has no errorlevel other than 0 (zero).
- As far as I am aware, the second check for 'if exists %folder' is not necessary because 'mkdir' will only return errorlevel 0 (zero) is it succeeds.